# Android: Camera2 switching between back and front camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I was working on taking a photo from my camera, and everything seems good, I'm using [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample, this code only offre the back camera so i added a button to switch between 2 cameras like this :

Boolean facingCamera = true; // initialization

```
onClick() {
    facingCamera = !facingCamera;
    closeCamera();
    openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight()); 
}
```

And i changed method setUpCameraOutputs code like this :

```
if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT ) {
    continue;
}
```

**To**

```
if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT && !facingCamera 
|| facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK && facingCamera ) {
    continue;
}
```

This work fine for Nexus 4 but for my LG-D802 is not working fine ( onConfigureFailed is called each time I try to change the camera )

How to fix this properly so it work fine on all devices?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check if CameraManager is giving you 2 available cameras? Use `cameraManager.getCameraIdList()` to check it. Also remember to get the right preview sizes for each camera using CameraCharacteristics:

```
StreamConfigurationMap rearMap = rearCameraCharacteristics.get(
      CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
StreamConfigurationMap frontMap = frontCameraCharacteristics.get(
      CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
```

After do that use  one of that values to initialize your preview, if you are using the same value for front and back camera maybe you are having problems with it because your front camera don't support that resolution size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think that's the problem , the log show that there is a problem with finding the appropriate resolution size sometimes, and sometimes the preview is stretched. I'm anable to find sample where you can use switch between facing camera and back camera, is there any ?

Comment: im facing the same problem, when I switch the camera sometimes the preview stretches, have you found a solution for it?

Comment: Great one! I was stuck for days in getting the right preview size while switching cameras. Thanks! :)